# How to call phone number ending with # using Android Dialer

Tags: android

How do I call a number ending with '#' sign using android dialer?

My code is as follows,

```
EditText firstNumber;
Button btnAdd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main23);

    Toast.makeText(Main23Activity.this,
            "Type in your Pin Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);





    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                numberSign = "#";

                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
                String text= et.getEditableText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(Main23Activity.this,
                        "Adding Money to your account has never been this easy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:*221*" + text + numberSign  ));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: So you want to convert 35 to `#`?

Comment: yes. thats exactly what i want to do.

Comment: Checkout the answer below.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:*215*" + text + "*" + text2 + "#"));

Comment: im trying to print that #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you call a number ending with '#' using android dialer. You need to encode and then parse.

Try the below code,

```
String text = et.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("*221*" + text + "#")));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this link  [you can get unicode and hex values](http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0012.html)

for example 36 can be stored in strings.xml as

```
   <string name="abcd">&#51;&#54;</string>
```

Comment: i get your concept. how would i call it within a toast popup