# Hash button does not work when placing a call

Tags: java, android

I'm making dial pad but when I call *123# then it call only *123. My # button does not show. Help me please.
My code is:

```
String s = buttonHesh.getText().toString();
editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + s);
```

Comment: So what value are you observing for `s`? You haven't shown anything that does any calling - which API are you using for that, and are you sure it supports including a hash at the end?

Comment: Guess: you're launching a `tel:` URI and forgot to encode the `#` URI metacharacter.

Comment: buttonHesh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String s = buttonHesh.getText().toString();
                editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + s);
            }
        });

Comment: May help, [Encode # in dialer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504787/how-to-call-phone-number-ending-with-using-android-dialer/38505063#38505063). Consider using `editText.append("text")` instead of `setText()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it B using Uri.encode() function.

```
String number = "*101#";
number =  number.replace("*", Uri.encode("*")).replace("#",Uri.encode("#"));
String uri = "tel:" + number;

Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
```

Or By replacing **%23** instad of **#**

```
String uri = "tel:" + " *101%23 ";

Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
```